# How does validation of JWT distinguish difference between token types?

Tags: validation, oauth-2.0, token, openid

I am playing around with building a custom Oauth2/OpenID library, and is having thoughts about validating the tokens.

I am using only JWT for all token types (Access, Refresh & ID), but I am thinking; How would the resource server validate ex. the access token, and make sure it is only access tokens from the issuer being accepted, and not refresh or ID tokens, since they would also be valid, hence they come from the same trusted issuer?

Likewise, how would make sure, the token sent with a refresh grant, is not just an valid access token, since it would also be verified...

I know an easy fix would be just making a custom claim, describing what kind of token it is, or using different signatures for each, but is there a "right" way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to separate the ID token from the Access token is by looking at the **typ** claim in the **JWT-header**.

Some IdentityProviders uses the at+jwt typ to indicate that the token is an access token that follows certain rules. But this is not a mandatory thing to follow.

```
{
  "typ":"at+JWT",
  "alg":"RS256",
  "kid":"RjEwOwOA"
}
```

Otherwise they can look at the claims inside the token to determine if it is an access or ID-token. The token-signature itself can't be used to determine the token type.

You can read more about the standard for access token [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-access-token-jwt-11) and [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/06/15/the-jwt-profile-for-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-and-identityserver/)

**Refresh** and **reference** tokens are typically not in a JWT format, instead they are more like a random string.

Comment: Oh it is actually specific written in the first link you posted:
"See the security considerations section for details on the
   importance of preventing OpenID Connect ID Tokens (as defined by
   Section 2 of [OpenID.Core]) from being accepted as access tokens by
   resource servers implementing this profile."

Awesome link you send me, I even found out serveral other things I have done wrong ;)

Comment: Great! Glad i could be of help! Why do you need to manually validate tokens? There are good libraries to do that.